# jquery mouseover not to hide element if the mouse is over popup window

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent, mouseover

I have few elements and by moving the mouse on each of them, popup window should appear, after the mouse spend few second on each of them. This I have done by the following script

```
var timeOutUserInfo;
$('a[datatype=popupAboutUser]').live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        timeOutUserInfo = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#popupUserInfo').show();
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeOutUserInfo);
        $('#popupUserInfo').fadeOut(250);
    }
});
```

the problem is that if the user should move the mouse on the #popupUserInfo, but as far as he does it, popup hides.
I have try a few things with checking if the mouse is over that popup and if not - to hide it, but was not able to do so.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<style type="text/css">
a.showinfo{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}

div.popupUserInfo{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
right:-100px;
top:0;
display:none;
}
</style>

<a href="whatever.com" class="showinfo">
  <div class="popupUserInfo">some user info here</div>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showinfo").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(".popupUserInfo").show();
      },function(){
        $(this).children(".popupUserInfo").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```